# Why Apache-kafka_2.9.1-0.8.2.1 is not starting after reboot in Cent OS 6.6?

Tags: centos, cron, apache-kafka

I've scheduled in crontab to auto start Kafka service after reboot as follows:

```
#crontab -l
@reboot /root/startup.sh

cat/root/startup.sh
cd /var/kafka_2.9.1-0.8.2.1/bin/
./kafka-server-start.sh ../config/server.properties > kafka.log 2>&1 &
```

If I run this script manually, it starts. In the same script other scripts also mentioned for auto start. They works fine but only kafka doesn't start. Please suggest where am I doing mistake?

Comment: It would be more productive if you add debugging statements to your script or crontab and see if they are executed.

Comment: What debugging statements I can add ?

Comment: Print stuff, touch stuff, whatever that could help you.